# Is it possible to work as an apprentice during a phd?

Tags: phd, psychology

I am currently an undergraduate student in Japan hoping to major in Psychology in the second year. I am thinking about studying Clinical Psychology for a Ph.D. to become a forensic psychologist in the future in Canada or America but I am wondering if I can study and work at the same time. Is this possible even for an international student? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by 'work" and "apprentice"? Most countries limit what sort of employment is open to those on a student visa, I think.

Comment: Except for internships that are part of a program, as an international student you are not allowed to work outside your studies in the U.S. I assume it’s the same in Canada.

Comment: Beside legal arguments, but just to show a point of view: doing my PhD (chemistry and physics environment) would have been impossible.

Comment: I am sorry I probably made a mistake (cuz english is not my first language), I meant whether I can get a job related to the pdh that I take. Is that impossible?